# Recursive query compute parent values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables Persons and Sales. In Person there is relation between child and parent, I want to compute 20 percent of parent values with the following condition

Persons

```
Id | ParentId | Name
1    NULL       Tom
2    1          Jake
3    2          Kate
4    3          Neil
```

Sales

```
PersonId | Sale
4          500
```

I want to get result like this

```
Id | ParentId | Name | Sale
1    Null       Tom    100  <-- (500*20)/100 left 400
2    1          Jake   80   <-- (400*20)/100 left 320
3    2          Kate   64   <-- (320*20)/100 left 256
4    3          Neil   256  <-- (320*80)/100
```

I wrote this query but it does not give appropriate result

```
;WITH cte_persons
AS
(
    SELECT p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Name, s.Price FROM Persons AS p
        INNER JOIN Sales AS s ON s.PersonId = p.Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Name, CAST((c.Price - (c.Price*80)/100) AS DECIMAL(6, 2)) FROM @Persons AS p
        INNER JOIN cte_persons AS c ON c.ParentId = p.Id
)
SELECT * FROM cte_persons
```

Comment: Please post data as text not images.

Comment: @Serg done ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a two steps algorithm. First traverse the hierachy to get max level. Then apply the level in a reverse order.

```
WITH cte_persons
AS
(
    SELECT 1 as level, p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Name, s.Price, p.Id AS base
    FROM Persons AS p
    INNER JOIN Sales AS s ON s.PersonId = p.Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level + 1, p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Name, c.Price, c.base
    FROM Persons AS p
    INNER JOIN cte_persons AS c ON c.ParentId = p.Id
)
SELECT Id, ParentId, Name,
   CASE level WHEN 1 
   THEN price - sum(delta) over(partition by base order by level desc) + delta 
   ELSE delta END sale
FROM ( 
   SELECT *,
     (power (0.8000, max(level) over(partition by base) - level) * 0.2) * price delta
   FROM cte_persons
) t
ORDER BY id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e57a640df5b85d18b687fb97f6d13faa)

Comment: thank you and just one question, why did you power percent by max(level)?

Comment: Every step applies the same factor 0.8, so going in reverse order the factor  power  `max(level) over() - level`  should be applied.

Comment: @id'7238 You just need to add a partitioning column by base person to get the calculation per person https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=0a4c55f41086e6fc5fafd11839382fd1 Although if you have a unique ID per sale it would be better to use that instead

Comment: Excellent stuff, no need to recurse twice like the other answer